# Authenticate Android application requests

Tags: android, http, authentication

I want to develop an Android application in which anonymous users can send requests to my server through HTTPS. I need to make sure that the requests are coming from my app since anyone can craft an HTPP request and send it. This is very critical in my app.

I read about GCM tokens, but I don't know if they can help me in my issue.

Is there a way to authenticate the requests (coming from the app) without hiding secret keys in code (because I read that hiding secrets is a bad practice as de-compilation is very trivial in Android).

Thanks

Comment: I also thought of getting the mobile app payment receipt from the play store and maybe send it to my server which in turns contacts google. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this issue after following this guide: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Basically, You use the GoogleAuthUtil class, available through Google Play services, to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You send the token to your back end and your back end can use it to quickly and cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the app.

When your server receives the token from your Android app, it’s really important that you verify it. This requires two steps:

1. Verify that it’s really signed by Google.
2. Verify that it’s really meant for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always generate a unique token for your user. And add that token in the header of your request and verify it on your backend.

Comment: If i generate a token in the header, how can I verify it in the server. Im assuming that the users are anonymous

Comment: The way I implemented this is when the user logins I generate a token for that user and after every request to the server from app, I verify that token.

Comment: But in this case anyone can login (use curl for example to send a request to your server), and the server will reply back with the token

Comment: You can use IP filtering or request rate limiting.

Comment: I thought of it but the main problem is I cannot rely on estimations. Plus a user can fake its IP easily, so he can write a bash script that keep changing the source IP and send different packets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your server could generate unique PIN for each user of your app and it is then sent to your app and displayed over the app.
2. Users, even though anonymous, are supposed to enter the same PIN before sending the response. In turn request could carry this PIN that server can verify that indeed it has come from the same app.
3. Further you can set timeout for validity of each PIN is valid so that it is not mis-used and always latest PIN generated are used at the end of any session.

One question further to be answered related to point 1: Is how to ensure that this PIN is sent to your app and not to any fake app.

Answer to that will be : For this every app will get unique applicationid when installed on android device. While installation, this applicationid could register with your server in a discreet manner. So this way you ensure that all your API calls are coming from registered app.